# Hazelcast version 3.2.4 - Serialization using kryo for a complex abstract object fails. Is there a way to implement KRYO serialization

Tags: java, apache-camel, hazelcast

Below is the object to be serialized. 
Issues: 
1. The object to be serialized is abstract and the classes which extends it are complex objects.I get Instantiation Error.
2. I thought to serialize only HubMessageBean which is part of the data stored in hazelcast IMap, but it only increased the heap space used but it did not decrease it. 
Please let me know if you could see any better option to serialize these objects. Right now, Java serialization is already in place.

```
  public abstract class HubMessageAggregate implements Serializable {

  abstract public void addHubMessage(HubMessageBean message) throws IllegalArgumentException;
  abstract public boolean isEmptyAggregate();
  }
```

Below is one of the class which implements the class to be serialized. I do have many such classes.

```
  public class CustomerAggregate extends HubMessageAggregate {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 4196808128400143445L;

  private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(CustomerAggregate.class);
   @Override
  public void addHubMessage(HubMessageBean message) {
  if(message == null) {
  LOG.fatal("Null message passed into aggregate.  WTF?");
  return;
  }

  if(message instanceof AccountMessage) {
  getAccountMessageList().add((AccountMessage) message);
  } else if (message instanceof CustomerMessage) {
  getCustomerMessageList().add((CustomerMessage) message);
  }

  private final Comparator<HubMessageBean> compareByMessageDateAscending = new HubMessageByTimestampAscending();

  @Override
  public int compare(HubMessageBean a, HubMessageBean b) {
  return compareByMessageDateAscending.compare(a, b) * -1;
  }
  };
  private List<AccountMessage> accountMessageList;
  private List<CustomerMessage> customerMessageList;
  private List<IdentifierMessage> identifierMessageList;
  private List<AddressMessage> addressMessageList;
  private List<CompanySpecialtyMessage> specialtyMessageList;
  private List<CompanySegmentationMessage> segmentationMessageList;
  private List<AccountLocationMessage> accountLocationMessageList;
  private List<TelecomNumberMessage> telecomNumberMessageList;
  private List<AccountAssociationMessage> accountAssociationMessageList;
```

Since serialization happens on its own, below is how I deserialize the object which results in instantiation error.

```
  HubMessageAggregate aggregate = messageStash.getAggregate(key);
```

Below is the KryoSerializer which i wrote which has the necessary config added.
      public class HubMessageAggregateKryoSerializer implements       StreamSerializer {

```
  private static final ThreadLocal<Kryo> kryoThreadLocal
  = new ThreadLocal() {
  @Override
  protected Kryo initialValue() {
  Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
  kryo.register(HubMessageAggregate.class);     
  return kryo;
  }
  };
```

StackTrace of Error:
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.lang.InstantiationError: com.manheim.webservices.ovcoutbound.beans.aggregate.HubMessageAggregate
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.handleException(SerializationServiceImpl.java:298)[hazelcast-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.toObject(SerializationServiceImpl.java:227)[hazelcast-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.NodeEngineImpl.toObject(NodeEngineImpl.java:156)[hazelcast-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at com.hazelcast.map.MapService.toObject(MapService.java:852)[hazelcast-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at com.hazelcast.map.proxy.MapProxyImpl.get(MapProxyImpl.java:53)[hazelcast-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at com.manheim.webservices.ovcoutbound.cep.cache.MessageStashHazelcastProvider.stashHubMessage(MessageStashHazelcastProvider.java:53)[MessageStashHazelcastProvider.class:]
    at com.manheim.webservices.ovcoutbound.cep.cache.MessageStashStrategy.aggregate(MessageStashStrategy.java:54)[MessageStashStrategy.class:]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregateProcessor.onAggregation(AggregateProcessor.java:474)[camel-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregateProcessor.doAggregation(AggregateProcessor.java:320)[camel-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregateProcessor.doProcess(AggregateProcessor.java:254)[camel-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregateProcessor.process(AggregateProcessor.java:179)[camel-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)[camel-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)[camel-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[camel-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.ChoiceProcessor.process(ChoiceProcessor.java:111)[camel-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)[camel-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)[camel-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]

Comment: I don't see a real question. What fails? What is the stacktrace? Which version of Hazelcast?

Comment: Sorry, I have added the stacktrace and other details.

Comment: Is there a Serializable wrapper object around it? If this is the case we lose contact to serialization and kryo won't be used either but Java standard Serialization will keep serializing objects.